# Arduino Uno R3, WS2812B, 1 strip of 60 leds, segmented in to 4

Tags: arduino-uno, ws2812

Arduino Uno R3, WS2812B, 1 strip of 60 leds, segmented in to 4.

Problem: Only want a single segment/fx_mode to run at any one time.

---

```
#include <WS2812FX.h>

#define LED_COUNT 60

#define LED_PIN 13

WS2812FX ws2812fx = WS2812FX(LED_COUNT, LED_PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

void setup() {

ws2812fx.init();

ws2812fx.setBrightness(85);

// divide the strip of 60 LEDs in to 4 segments

ws2812fx.setSegment(0,  0, 14, FX_MODE_COMET, BLUE,  3000, false); 

ws2812fx.setSegment(1, 15, 29, FX_MODE_SCAN, RED, 3000, true); 

ws2812fx.setSegment(2, 30, 44, FX_MODE_SCAN, BLUE,  3000, false); 

ws2812fx.setSegment(3, 45, 60, FX_MODE_SCAN, RED, 3000, true); 

ws2812fx.start(); 
}

void loop() {

ws2812fx.service();
}
```

Comment: and doesn't it? ... what is your question?

Comment: aren't they individually addressable LEDs?

Comment: look at example code in the arduino IDE

Comment: your post doesn't say much of anything about what you are trying to do  ... the example code is right there in the Arduino IDE on your computer

Comment: Please let me explain this more.  I have 1 strip of 60 leds, segmented in to 4 parts with 4 different FX_MODES and colours. I only want 1 segment or FX_MODE to be ON at any one time...  Segment(0, to be ON and the rest are OFF.  Next Segment(1, is ON and the rest are OFF. Next Segment(2, is ON and the rest are OFF. Next Segment(3, ON and all the rest are OFF.

Comment: You can help by putting the additional information in the question by editing it. As it is now, your question only consists of unformatted code with no descrtiption of what's wrong with it or what you're trying to accomplish. It's unlikely to be answered like this.

Comment: You have to look at the *ws2812fx* library to see what the code is doing. I think it is described pretty well [here](https://github.com/kitesurfer1404/WS2812FX/blob/master/extras/WS2812FX%20Users%20Guide.md), including how the `setSegment` function works. You can leave out the `ws2812fx.setSegment(1, ...) to (3, ...)` to stop using that segment. You can change the amount of LEDs in a segment with the second and third parameters, i.e. `ws2812fx.setSegment(0, 0, 4, ...)` will only light the first 5 LEDs (0..4). Just experiment a bit with the parameters.

Comment: I'm just an unpaid volunteer trying to help you in my free time, which I will stop doing after your comment. *I can't read your mind*. You need to put all of this information in the question. What about "pause/delay/time/count"? It's not in your question. How was I supposed to know that you already changed the amount of LEDs in each segment? You did not mention it anywhere.

Comment: I've tried to read everything I could on here and in library examples, on youtube and google.  Finally post a question here at 3am as I thought the problem would be obvious to a pro.  It's now 5am and way past bed time lol good night

Comment: Your question reads like: "Problem: I want to bake a cake. Here is the recipe". You don't say what actually happens when you follow the recipe. Even a pro can't answer that.

Answer (score 1):

The used library doesn't give you the direct possibility to automate the segment changes. So you need to write that code yourself.

Currently you are setting up all segment in `setup()` and starting them together via `start()`. Instead you should add the corresponding segment only, when it should be on, and removing all segments, that should not run. In the following I don't remove and add a segment, but I'm replacing the previous segment (described below)

I propose a code like the following, to light up each element after the other for a specific time each (**not tested**):

```
#include <WS2812FX.h>

#define LED_COUNT 60

#define LED_PIN 13

#define SEGMENT_INTERVAL    3000
unsigned long segment_timestamp;
uint8_t current_segment = 0;
#define SEGMENT_N   4

WS2812FX ws2812fx = WS2812FX(LED_COUNT, LED_PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

void setup() {
    ws2812fx.init();
    ws2812fx.setBrightness(85);
    ws2812fx.start(); 
}

void loop() {
    if(millis()-segment_timestamp > SEGMENT_INTERVAL){
        segment_timestamp += SEGMENT_INTERVAL;
        switch(current_segment){
            case 0:
                ws2812fx.setSegment(0,  0, 14, FX_MODE_COMET, BLUE,  3000, false);
                break;
            case 1:
                ws2812fx.setSegment(0, 15, 29, FX_MODE_SCAN, RED, 3000, true);
                break;
            case 2:
                ws2812fx.setSegment(0, 30, 44, FX_MODE_SCAN, BLUE,  3000, false);
                break;
            case 3:
                ws2812fx.setSegment(0, 45, 60, FX_MODE_SCAN, RED, 3000, true);
                break;
        }
        current_segment = (current_segment + 1) % SEGMENT_N;
    }
    ws2812fx.service();
}
```

**What happens here?** First we use the `millis()` function in the pattern of the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example to time the change of segments to every 3s (3000ms) without blocking the execution of the other code (here the service routine of the LED animation). I will not go into detail here, since this principle is described at numerous places through the web and this site. Just search for something like "Arduino millis" or "Arduino Blink without delay". Now is only important, that the code inside the if statement will be executed every 3s (can be changed with `SEGMENT_INTERVAL`).

In the if statement we use a switch statement to set the corresponding segment, that should be activated at that time. Here we always set the segment 0, since only one segment is active at any time. Instead of removing the previous segment and adding the new one, we just change the previous segment to the data of the new segment.

With the line

```
current_segment = (current_segment + 1) % SEGMENT_N;
```

we increment to the next segment, while wrapping around from segment 3 to segment 1 via the modulo operator `%`. This is needed to loop through the segments.

The call to `ws2812fx.service()` is still needed, since it handles the actual animation of the current segment.

---

Note, that the above code can still be improved. You could save all the segment data in an array of structs and replace the switch statement with one line, using the `current_segment`'th element of the array. I will leave that improvement to you.